# Properties of divisibility

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know if it's true if $a|b$ and $c|d$, then $ac|bd$. I prove in this way: if $a|b$ and $c|d$, then there are $k_1$ and $k_2$, such that $b=k_1a$ and $d=k_2c$, thus $bd=k_1k_2ac$ and $ac|bd$.

Is my proof true? I've already read several books including Niven's book and they don't mention this important property.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your proof works.

Comment: Yeah that looks like a good proof!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. If can also be deduced by multiplying factions after checking the trivial cases $\,a,c=0,\,$ i.e. $\,b/a,d/c\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, (b/a)(d/c) = bd/(ac)\in\Bbb Z,\,$ so $\,ac\mid bd$.

Some books derive it from the constant case $\,a\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, an\mid bn,\,$ thus $\,ac\mid bc\mid bd,\,$ which may explain why they do not explicitly mention it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks bill